# QBSDK in Windows 7 (QuickBooks)

Tags: c++, windows-7, quickbooks

I am attempting to get the QBSDK running on my Windows 7 machine. I am trying to run the sample program called EventHandler.  It is run in conjunction with the sample EventSubscribe. I have compiled these in Visual Studio 2008.  The EventHandler has a option in the File menu called Register Call Back Interface.  When I run that it indicates that the COM connection has been created, however when I try to subscribe to an event in the EventSubscribe sample program it gives me the error  “The callback application cannot be found from the CLSID or ProgID provided in the subscription request.”

On my Windows 7 machine after I did the Register the Callback Interface I noticed that the Unregister command was not highlighted.  I also compiled this on a Windows XP machine with Visual Studio 2008 and I noticed the Unregister was highlighted.  I do not have Quickbooks on the Windows XP machine though.

I have tried many things to get this to work…  Any idea what is happening?

I am using C++

Thanks,

Jim

Comment: The C++ code in EventHandler is: `code` _Module.UpdateRegistryFromResource(IDR_EVENTHANDLER, TRUE); _Module.RegisterServer(FALSE); AfxMessageBox( "COM Callback registered.\n\nIf QuickBooks is currently running, restart it to pick up the new registration." );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not directly describe your situation but the concept is similar.  Starting with Vista, there were quite a few workarounds with QuickBooks SDK (and other COM-based technology) that required "Run As Administrator" to configure due to Windows UAC restrictions.

From the SDK documentation:

```
After you subscribe your menu extension events and
register them as documented, you need to run QB
using "Run As Administrator." This only has to be
done ONCE, after running QB as admin once, your
menu items will continue to show up and menu
events will be received by your event handler without
running QB as admin.
```

The general principle is that even if you are running Windows under an Administrative account, you may need to "Run As Administrator" both the QuickBooks UI, and your application that uses QBSDK, during the configuration process.  Once all the registration and configuration is done it should work as a normal user.

Comment: I had considered that but thought that since I have the only user account on my Windows 7 machine, I was the administrator. I am positive that I have sysadmin privs on the Windows XP so that makes sense. I will try it....  Thanks!!